# how can I copy One Note page titles into 1 page?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote, merge

I have one note 2013 and Id like to be able to create a table of contents, so to speak.  How can I combine or merge page titles, only the page titles into one page?  I know how to combine all pages into one, but I only want the titles.  Thank you.
Bill

Answer (score 4):

Select the pages whose titles you want to copy (if they're in the same notebook/section you can select them all at the same time).  Then, right click and choose Copy Link to Page.

Paste the titles on a OneNote page, re-select them, right click, and choose Remove Link.  You can also paste them into MS Word, re-select them and push Shitf+Ctrl+F9.

Happy OneNoting!

Answer (score 0):

Seems the right way is to manually create  a TOC (Table Of Content) *afterwards*.

To do it more "automatically", you can install the [Onetastic add in](https://getonetastic.com/?r=download): Works great!

You can also create a new entry in your TOC, simply by typing [[your new page' title]]

See https://onenote2016.wordpress.com/2016/02/15/table-des-matieres/ for guidance (in French)

Comment: You shouldn't include a question in your answer. Your answer should be complete and stand alone if heathkat happens to ever remove their answer. Just some helpful advice. This will help improve your answer